# Apply a callback to a multidimensional array

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have this in PHP:

```
$data = array("test"=>array("abc"=>"xyz"));
```

I want to append '**data:**' with array values, so output will be '**data:xyz**' for that **$data** array.

Its just a sample. How can I do this with multi dimension arrays. i.e; appending string with multi dimension array values ? Can I do with persistent values in same array so I can re-use this ?

Comment: You need to define in _far_ greater depth how you wish your array to be serialised. Give some sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: Input: $data = array("test"=>array("abc"=>"xyz"));
Output: $data = array("test"=>array("abc"=>"data:xyz"));

Can you make it recursive upto n level ?

Comment: You wish to prepend the text "data:" to every Array value on every leaf?

Comment: @ Tomalak Geret'kal: Yes, that's perfect for what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about human-readability and just want to [serialise](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) an Array for later use:

```
<?php
$data = Array("test" => Array("abc" => "xyz"));
$str  = serialize($data);

echo 'data:' . $str;
print_r(unserialize($str));

// data:<some characters here>
// Array("test" => Array("abc" => "xyz"));
?>
```

If you're trying to modify the original array such that the text "data:" is prepended to [every](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) value in the Array on every level:

```
<?php
$data = Array("test" => Array("abc" => "xyz"));

function f($array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      if (is_array($value))
         $array[$key] = f($value);
      else
         $array[$key] = "data:" . $value;
   }
   return $array;
}
$data = f($data);
print_r($data);

// Output: Array("test" => Array("abc" => "data:xyz"));
?>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks Tomalak Geret'kal.

Comment: `function f($array)` needs to `return $array` at the end.  And `f($data);` should be `$data=f($data);`.

Comment: @Mark: No problem. Please note that I took a massive guess here and got really lucky; your question was quite vague and it would be easier in future if you provided more information about precisely what inputs and outputs -- you'll need to give several, showing different cases -- you expect from the algorithm. Good luck!

Comment: @Mark: For example, when you said "so output will be 'data:xyz' for that $data array" you should have said "so the value of $data['test']['abc'] will become 'data:xyz'".

Comment: @Rocket: Ah, no, I meant to make `f` take `$array` by reference. Eh well, this'll do too.

Comment: If you wanted `$array` by reference, then `$array[$key] = f($value);` wouldn't work.

Comment: @Rocket: Oh, I'm not saying I didn't mess it up :)

Comment: @Rocket: Thanks, but I know how to do it. I merely made some typos in my post. The current by-val solution, as I said, will be fine.

Answer (score 5):

There's a PHP function that *"[applies] a user function recursively to every member of an array"* it's [array_walk_recursive()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php).

Here's an example for PHP 5.3 that uses a closure:

```
array_walk_recursive($data, function(&$str) { $str = "data:$str"; });
```

If you feel fancy, you can make it a function that accepts a configurable prefix, such as:

```
function prepend(&$v, $k, $prefix)
{
    $v = $prefix . $v;
}

array_walk_recursive($data, 'prepend', 'data:');
```

Comment: Doesn't work multidimensionally (but could be made to easily). +1 for `array_walk_recursive`.

Comment: It should work regardless of how deeply nested the arrays are. Do you have an example of an array where that wouldn't work?

Comment: @JoshDavis sadly this answer won't work on multidimensional arrays. As per the PHP doc : "Any key that holds an array will not be passed to the function." Why that is, is beyond me. Seems counter-intuitive for a function named "recursive".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I would suggest that you provide your answer of how you would actually achieve that, for the benefit of others with the same question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that you want to apply a custom function to your array but only to an specific key => value pair, this is my improved version:

```
$data = array( "test" => array("abc" => "xyz", 'def'=> 2), 'test2' =>  array ( 'abc' => 'jkl', 'def' => 5) );
$keytochange = 'def';
$apply = 'md5';
$data = f($data,$keytochange,$apply);

function f($array, $keytochange, $apply) 
{
   foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
   {
      if (is_array($value))
         $array[$key] = f($value,$keytochange,$apply);
      else
         $array[$keytochange] = $apply( $value );
   }
   return $array;
}

print_r($data);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [test] => Array
        (
            [abc] => xyz
            [def] => c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c
        )
    [test2] => Array
        (
            [abc] => jkl
            [def] => e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To modify each item in an array, you can use the function `array_map()`

Example:

```
  function Prepend($s)
  {
    return 'Data:'.$s;
  }

  $old_array = array('abc','def','ghi','xyz');

  $new_Array = array_map('Prepend',$old_array);

  var_dump($old_array);
  var_dump($new_Array);
```

Output:

```
array
  0 => string 'abc' (length=3)
  1 => string 'def' (length=3)
  2 => string 'ghi' (length=3)
  3 => string 'xyz' (length=3)
array
  0 => string 'Data:abc' (length=8)
  1 => string 'Data:def' (length=8)
  2 => string 'Data:ghi' (length=8)
  3 => string 'Data:xyz' (length=8)
```